# IntelliJ. What does PSI stand for?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'd like to develop IntelliJ plugin and have small question.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/psi-viewer.html

In above document, what does PSI mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I got it. It's **Program Structure Interface**.

http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/psi_elements.html

Someone complained PSI meaning like me a year ago: [link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/11/psi-viewer/#comment-369273)